# i want to store value of check box checked in repeater control on page refresh

Tags: asp.net

i have repeater control in my page ,and it contains Questions and its options in check boxes .
i want to store that information if user refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

You can store this info e.g. in cookies with help of a JS handler function of the onclick client events of your checkboxes